# Parallel file reading OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp

I would like to develop a simple program that can read different pieces of a file simultaneously.
I'm using C, OpenM and GCC.

I have a file with the following structure:

```
 --------
| HEADER |
| ARRAY1 |
| TEXT   |
| ARRAY2 |
 --------
```

Keeping in mind that the `HEADER` and `ARRAY1` sections are **independent** of each other, I would like to understand if I can use a multi-thread strategy to **read** these first pieces of the file at the same time.

I implemented a very easy test solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct FILEHEADER {
  int x;
  int y;
  int elemNr;
} FileHeader;

static const char *filename = "test_data.bin";

void readFileHeader(FILE *fp, FileHeader *header, int nr)
{
  fread(header, sizeof(int), nr, fp);
}

void readArray1(FILE *fp, int *array1, int n)
{
  fseek(fp, sizeof(FileHeader), SEEK_SET);
  fread(array1, sizeof(int), sizeof(int) * n, fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int thread_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  omp_set_num_threads(thread_count);

  const int n = 10;

  // create the file and write the data inside

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

  FileHeader headerW = {.x = 5, .y = 9, .elemNr = 3};
    BYTE *buffer = (BYTE*)&headerW;
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(int) * headerW.elemNr, fp);

  int *array = calloc (n, sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = i;

  buffer = (BYTE*)array;
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), sizeof(int) * n, fp);

  printf("write section\n");
  printf("\nheader:\n\t");
  printf("x: %d\n\ty: %d\n\telemNr: %d\n", headerW.x, headerW.y, headerW.elemNr);

  printf("\narray:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("\tarray[%d]: %d\n", i, array[i]);

  printf("\n");

  free(array);
    fclose(fp);

  // open the file and read the data inside

  FILE *fp1 = fopen(filename, "rb");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(filename, "rb");

  FileHeader headerR = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .elemNr = 0};
  int *array1 = calloc (n, sizeof(int));

  #pragma omp parallel sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    readFileHeader(fp1, &headerR, 3);

    #pragma omp section
    readArray1(fp2, array1, n);
  }

  printf("read section\n");
  printf("\nheader:\n\t");
  printf("x: %d\n\ty: %d\n\telemNr: %d\n", headerR.x, headerR.y, headerR.elemNr);

  printf("\narray1:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("\tarray1[%d]: %d\n", i, array1[i]);

  // read the other parts of the file and do something

  free(array1);
  fclose(fp2);
  fclose(fp1);

  return 0;
}
```

This solution compiles and works.
However because of its simplicity, I'm not sure if it is really run in parallel.

Anyway, what I'm asking is if the idea behind is correct, in other words, can I **safely read** different parts of the same file, at the same time, by using a multi-thread strategy?

If the answer were to be no, there is another way to do that by using OpenMp?

Comment: AFAIK there's no garantee that the I/O instructions are thread-safe. And if they are, I would expect little or even no performance improvement by just parallelizing I/Os on the same device: in all cases the drive will process the read requests sequentially, not in parallel. On a HDD it could even degrade the performances, by forcing the heads going back and forth if reading files (or pieces of file) at very different physical locations of the platters.

Comment: `fread` _is_ thread safe, but that's not enough. The thread safety is that `fread` is atomic. But, two subsequent calls are not. So, the `fseek` followed by `fread` is _not_ atomic. Given two threads: `tA` and `tB`. You _could_ get: `tA:fseek tB:fread tA:fread` so the `tA:fread` would _not_ occur at the position set by the `fseek`. That's why there is `pread`. You could try (in `tA`): `tA:flockfile tA:fseek tA:fread tA:funlockfile`

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that you have _two_ separate `fopen` calls. So, they do _not_ interact because you're only doing read operations. But, I tend to agree with PierU that this could degrade performance. The usual is to have the main thread read in the data [into arrays]. Then, the threads can operate on sections. You could also forego `fread` and just do a single `mmap` in the main thread. But, this might also degrade because it's causing the kernel to non-sequential access to the file [even if both threads access the file sequentially themselves].

Comment: I didn't think about what has been said by @PierU. Thanks for your comments, I'll try to apply the parallelization to other aspects of the program.

Comment: On a HDD, it is better to read a big chunk *serially* and compute it in parallel (as said previously). On a SATA SSD, it depends: it could be faster assuming the chunks are not too small. On a Nvme SSD, it is not rare for reads to be faster in parallel but this is generally the case for many small random chunks. If you want to try that using multiple threads, then you likely need to do 1 `fopen` per thread to avoid internal locks. Some IO subsystems are protected by a giant lock while some are more parallel. Results are clearly platform-dependent.

Comment: Note there are fast platform-dependent low-level APIs to read files (especially designed for SSDs). If you do not care about portability, this might be a good option. On Windows there is IO-Ring, and IO-Uring on Linux. The later is designed for fast asynchronous IO without kernel calls.

Comment: @PierU Can you provide links to documentation substantiating your statement 'in all cases the drive will process the read requests sequentially, not in parallel.' Does this apply even if, as in the example, there are multiple file descriptors on the same file? I wouldn't expect HDDs to handle this approach well but I am curious about improving SSD performance by using file operations on multiple threads on the same file and different files. Does anyone know of any IO benchmark tests done using file operations on multiple threads?

Comment: @SimonGoater this is obvious for HDDs, as the heads cannot be at multiple locations simultaneously. For SSDs it could be different, but the SATA interface can only process the commands sequentially from a single queue (although with some [reordering](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing)). The [NVME interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVMe) has multiple command queues to achieve some I/O parallelism, but it's not clear to me if read commands are really executed simultaneously in the SSD or if it's more a "hiding the latency" approach.

Comment: 'Hiding the latency' could be well worth capitalising on. It would be an interesting experiment I think, but I don't have NVME SSDs.